# When plotting using geom_abline with ggplot, there are no tick marks on the axes even when specified

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using geom_abline to plot lines, and when I just plot lines all my tick marks on my axes disappear. I can't figure out why or how to put them back

```
library( tidyverse )

dat = data.frame( id = 1:3,
                  pi.0 = c( 0, 1, 2 ),
                  pi.1 = c(0.15, 0.05, -0.35 ) )

ggplot( dat, aes( group=id ) ) +
  geom_abline( aes( intercept=pi.0, slope=pi.1 ) ) +
  coord_cartesian( xlim=c(0,9), ylim=c( -5, 7 ) ) +
  scale_x_continuous( breaks=0:9 ) +
  labs( y="Outcome", x="Time" )
```

I would expect to see tick marks on the x axis at 0, 1, ..., 9.  But I don't!  Why not?  And how do I get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `scale_*_continuous` to set the limits and not `coord_cartesian`.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame( id = 1:3,
                  pi.0 = c( 0, 1, 2 ),
                  pi.1 = c(0.15, 0.05, -0.35 ) )

ggplot(dat, aes( group=id ) ) +
  geom_abline( aes(intercept=pi.0, slope=pi.1 ) ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0:9), limits=c(0, 9) ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c( -5, 7 ) ) +
  labs( y="Outcome", x="Time" )
```